# Wordpress Gutenberg PluginDocumentSettingPanel not working with controls?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add a custom meta field to the gutenberg document panel and used [this doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/plugin-document-setting-panel/). For the custom meta field I used [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/managing-wordpress-metadata-in-gutenberg-using-a-sidebar-plugin/).
The problem I have occurs when trying to put them together.

Here is my code so far:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost
const { PanelBody, PanelRow, TextControl } = wp.components

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        name="custom-panel"
        title="Custom Panel"
        className="custom-panel"
    >
        <TextControl 
          value={wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield']}
          label={ "Text Meta" }
          onChange={(value) => wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({meta: {_myprefix_text_metafield: value}})}
        />
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
)
registerPlugin('plugin-document-setting-panel-demo', {
    render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo
})
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Ivan I solved this side issue :)

---

My Sidebar looks okay at first:

[image]

But when I try to change the inputs value it isn't updated (but the storage in wp.data is). I can't delete it, too. It stays at it's initial value. When I remove the part where I set the initial value it works like it should be but since I need the initial value this isn't an option for me ;)

Here an example log from the console when I add an "x" to the end of the input (as mentioned above the text in the input itself doesn't change)

[image]

Does anyone know how to make the input field working properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/ plugin installed, because PluginDocumentSettingPanel is not fully implemented in core WP yet. It should be for 5.3 version, as per [these tweets](https://twitter.com/mor10/status/1149037633525256192).

Second, you don't need the interval function for the wp.plugins. The reason it is undefined at first is that WordPress doesn't know that you need the wp-plugins loaded first. From the [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/)

> If you wanted to use the PlainText component from the editor module, first you would specify wp-editor as a dependency when you enqueue your script

The same applies for all other modules (read scripts, like 'wp-plugins').
You have to add the 'wp-plugins' script as a dependency, when registering your js plugin script:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Sidebar plugin
*/

function sidebar_plugin_register() {
    wp_register_script(
        'plugin-sidebar-js',
        plugins_url( 'plugin-sidebar.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-plugins', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-element' ) // <== the dependencies array is important!
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sidebar_plugin_register' );

function sidebar_plugin_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin-sidebar-js' );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'sidebar_plugin_script_enqueue' );
```

The PHP above is taken from the [official WP documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/plugin-sidebar-1-up-and-running/).

I would also suggest reading thoroughly this [awesome tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/managing-wordpress-metadata-in-gutenberg-using-a-sidebar-plugin/) from Css Tricks. It goes in depth about setting up an ESNext environment with only the [@wordpress/scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts) package. It goes over the dependencies, adding meta fields and much more :) I hope this helps!

--------------- Initial answer ends here ---------------

**Edit:** After testing the code from the author, I found out a couple of issues. First of all, there was a missing closing tag for the TextControl. Second, I added Higher order components from the wp-data package, which I then used to "enhance" the TextControl, so that it doesn't manipulate or read data directly, but abstract that logic into it's [higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). The code looks like so:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { TextControl } = wp.components;
const { withSelect, withDispatch, dispatch, select } = wp.data;
// All the necessary code is pulled from the wp global variable,
// so you don't have to install anything
// import { withSelect, withDispatch, dispatch, select } from "@wordpress/data";
// !!! You should install all the packages locally,
// so your editor could access the files so you could
// look up the functions and classes directly. 
// It will not add to the final bundle if you
// run it through wp-scripts. If not, you can
// still use the wp global variable, like you have done so far.



let TextController = props => (
    <TextControl
        value={props.text_metafield}
        label={__("Text Meta", "textdomain")}
        onChange={(value) => props.onMetaFieldChange(value)}
    />
);

TextController = withSelect(
    (select) => {
        return {
            text_metafield: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield']
        }
    }
)(TextController);

TextController = withDispatch(
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            onMetaFieldChange: (value) => {
                dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { _myprefix_text_metafield: value } })
            }
        }
    }
)(TextController);

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => {
    // Check if a value has been set
    // This is for editing a post, because you don't want to override it everytime
    if (!select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield']) {
        // Set initial value
        dispatch('core/editor').editPost({ meta: { _myprefix_text_metafield: 'Your custom value' } });
    }
    return (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
            name="custom-panel"
            title="Custom Panel"
            className="custom-panel"
        >
            <TextController />
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    )
};
registerPlugin('plugin-document-setting-panel-demo', {
    render: PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo
})
```

Since the meta field is registered with an underscore as a first symbol in the name, WordPress will not allow you to save it, because it treats it as a private value, so you need to add extra code, when registering the field:

```
function myprefix_register_meta()
{
    register_post_meta('post', '_myprefix_text_metafield', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
        'single' => true,
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
        'auth_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can('edit_posts');
        }
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'myprefix_register_meta');
```

Again, all of this is explained in the [Css tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/managing-wordpress-metadata-in-gutenberg-using-a-sidebar-plugin/).

Comment: thx for your answer but this is exactly the tutorial I linked in my question and it doesn't work the way I described above ;) But the trick with the missing dependency did at least the trick for the wp.plugins problem. I used dependencies but simply forgot to add it. And yes I have the gutenberg plugin installed. I still can't "edit" my text input.

I added an image to my initial post clarifying the edit-problem

Comment: So, first of all, make sure you registered the [Meta field with PHP](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/plugin-sidebar-3-register-meta/). I don't know if you did that already, just making sure.

I tried your code and there  is a missing closing of the `<TextControl>` component. How do you set the initial value? For me it is blank.

Comment: I registered it. I also registered other fields, they all appear in the wp.data storage and in my panel. But they all share the same problem that I can't "edit" them. You are right, in my code above was some typo but the tag is closed here. The initial value is set in `value={wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield']}`. When your field is blank it means that you don't have any registered meta called "_myprefix_text_metafield".

Comment: @Insomnia88 Check my edit. I believe all should be well now :)

Comment: I used your code and it still doesn't work the way it should. Yes, I can edit the field now but in my question I also stated that I can edit it when I don't set an initial value. This seems faulty in your code. Where is the `props.text_metafield` defined? I noticed the same back when I read the tutorial but the comments are closed and nobody mentioned it. The problem there is that the author build a custom panel that is not part of the document panel and this is not something I want. That's why I linked the other tutorial, too. Have you tried the code yourself?

Comment: OK, @Insomnia88, I have made another edit to the JS code. Now it includes a default value for your input. It is in the `PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo` function. Please, refer to my inline comments.

The `props.text_metafield` is set in the `TextController = withSelect(` part of the code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work it should. As always, when I set the content to something different I can edit the field but it is not saved. Maybe I should have made this more clear, sorry about that.
What I understand as "works as intendend" is = I can edit the field, save the post and have the saved value as initial when I reload the page. Like in every other block I built before.
Maybe this is a bug from wordpress/gutenberg? I wouldn't consider it but it's the only thing left to assume if nothing works :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201645/discussion-between-ivan-shulev-and-insomnia88).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - values were not being updated in the field and in the database - and, after some research, I have found that the reason for this is that you should add `'custom-fields'` to the `'supports'` array in your call to [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), like this:

```
register_post_type(
    'my_post_type_slug',
    array(
        ...
       'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ),
        ...
    )
);
```

You can test that this works by calling `wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPost().meta` in your JavaScript console, when the block editor is loaded. If your post type does not add support for `'custom-fields'`, this call will return `undefined`; if it does, it will return an empty array (or rather, an array with the already existing meta from the database). This behavior is mentioned [in the Gutenberg docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/plugin-sidebar-3-register-meta/), in a note on registering your post meta:

> To make sure the field has been loaded, query the block editor [internal data structures](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/designers-developers/developers/data/), also known as stores. Open your browser’s console, and execute this piece of code:
>
> ```
> wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPost().meta;
> ```
>
> Before adding the `register_post_meta` function to the plugin, this code returns a void array, because WordPress hasn’t been told to load any meta field yet. After registering the field, the same code will return an object containing the registered meta field you registered.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a similar implementation recently, and worked through a bunch of examples as well. Between the above-mentioned articles, and [this great series by one of the Automattic devs](https://unfoldingneurons.com/2020/wordpress-data-series-overview-and-introduction), I got a working version of the above example using the newer `useSelect` and `useDispatch` custom hooks. It's really quite similar, but utilizes custom hooks from React 16.8 for a slightly more concise dev experience:

(Also, using `@wordpress/scripts`, so the imports are from the npm packages instead of the `wp` object directly, but either would work.)

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

const TextController = (props) => {
  const meta = useSelect(
    (select) =>
      select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')['_myprefix_text_metafield']
  );
  const { editPost } = useDispatch('core/editor');
  return (
    <TextControl
      label={__("Text Meta", "textdomain")}
      value={meta}
      onChange={(value) => editPost({ meta: { _myprefix_text_metafield: value } })}
    />
  );
};

const PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo = () => {
  return (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
      name="custom-panel"
      title="Custom Panel"
      className="custom-panel"
    >
      <TextController />
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
  );
};

export default PluginDocumentSettingPanelDemo;
```

Hopefully that helps someone else searching.